# Can we make a convergent series absolutely convergent under certain conditions?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Suppose $\sum a_n$ is convergent,can we impose some condition on this series to make the series absolutely convergent?

Except some trivial conditions that it has finitely many positive or negative terms etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In $\mathbb{R}$ (resp. $\mathbb{C}$) the absolute convergence is equivalent to the condition that for any permutation $\pi \colon \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_{\pi(n)}$ is convergent (known as *Riemann rearrangement theorem*). In general, you cannot say more! (Of course, you could use e.g. the integral comparison test, if $|a_n|$ can be extenend to an monotically decreasing function $f$ in order to get absolute convergence. However, this is - of course - only a very special case.)

Note that by the Theorem of Dvoretzky-Rogers this statement is false in infinite dimensional banach spaces. (There is an unconditional convergent series which is not absolute convergent.)